# R, Using a shapefile to extract values from a Landsat Image

Tags: shapefile, r, landsat-8

> Using the the shapefie "roi.shp" provided. Extract values from the
> Landsat image and plot the spectral profiles of the different
> materials i.e Water,Urban or built-up areas, roads, and vegetation.

I have the folowing piece of code:

```
##Load shape files
samp <- readOGR(paste0(layer="roi.shp")) ##roi.shp is a shapefile for a region of interest

##Generate point samples
ptsamp <- spsample(samp, 300, type='regular')

##Add land cover class
ptsamp$class <- over(ptsamp, samp)$class

# extract values with points
df <- extract(s, ptsamp)

# To see some of the reflectance values
head(df)
```

The following error is given on the
'ptsamp$class <- over(ptsamp, samp)$class' line

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “SpatialPointsDataFrame” object: number of rows in data.frame and SpatialPoints don't match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there's a `class` column in the shapefile, and hence in `samp`? I get your error if I try and assign a non-existent value from `samp`:

```
> ptsamp$class = over(ptsamp, samp)$class
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “SpatialPointsDataFrame” object: number of rows in data.frame and SpatialPoints don't match
```

but with one that does, it works:

```
> ptsamp$AFF = over(ptsamp, samp)$AFF
> names(samp)
 [1] "SP_ID"  "NAME"   "ID_x"   "COUNT"  "SMR"    "LONG"   "LAT"    "PY"    
 [9] "EXP_"   "AFF"    "X_COOR" "Y_COOR" "ID_y"
```

Check `class` is in `names(samp)`. You've not given us your shapefile so we can't test.

I've used the `scot_BNG` data from `example(readOGR)`.

Comment: I changed the code to : ptsamp$CLASS_NAME <- over(ptsamp, samp)$CLASS_NAME which solved my issue thank you!